# Java SOAP XML Serialization Error

Tags: java, xml, soap, deserialization, xmlserializer

I have a .net server hosting some webservices.

I am making a Java client. I used Apache CFX to autocreate some useful classes based on the given wsdl file.

However, when I make the call in Java to the webservice I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://localhost/MyService:ManualAddress. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Company.Product.Application.Services.DataContracts.LetterProcessManualAddress. The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 2119.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy37.processEnrollmentTraditionalDeficiency(Unknown Source)
at com.parc.peimage.PEFormViewer$3.run(PEFormViewer.java:2582)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Manual address is a JAXBElement, and my XML is not being created properly because of this error.

This is my code for creating the Address:

```
// SET manual address variables
com.parc.SomeCompanyAPI.Address MA;
MA = new Address();
MA.setAddressInCareOfName(new JAXBElement <String>  (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "MyName"));
MA.setAddressLineOne(new JAXBElement <String>  (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "MyAdd1"));
MA.setAddressLineTwo(new JAXBElement <String> (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "MyAdd2"));
MA.setCity(new JAXBElement <String> (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "MyAdd3"));
MA.setStateCode(new JAXBElement <String> (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "MyAdd4"));
MA.setZipCode(new JAXBElement <String> (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "MyAdd5"));
JAXBElement <Address> majax = new JAXBElement <Address> (new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), Address.class, MA);
letter.setAddress(majax);
JAXBElement <String> provider = new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("http://example.com/SampleService"), String.class, "bob");
letter.setProviderName(provider);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems strange to me that CXF would generate setters taking a `JAXBElement` instead of a string. A possible solution to that can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4583912/139595), the `generateElementProperty` attribute is further documented in a [WSIT Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19502-01/820-1072/ahiid/index.html).

The exception you are getting here is because you are using the wrong constructor for [QName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html), you should specify both the namespace URI and the local name of the element as parameters.