# Compilation errors on Jenkins : generated ObjectFactory differs from local build

Tags: maven, jenkins, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm currently working on a project which use an external WebService.
We have the WSDL and several related xsd files and use a wsdl2java goal of cxf-codegen-plugin to generate the classes from this WSDL.

I have a CustomerInfo object to set in a request I pass to the WS when calling it, and as I need JAXBElements to populate it, I use the generated ObjectFactory.

The project packages smoothly on my laptop, using maven package either inside IDE or via command-line.

However, once on the CI platform, I get compilation errors when trying to package it : all the createCustomerInfoXXXX() methods are missing.

I checked the Jenkins workspace : the CustomerInfo class exists, and is in the same package than the ObjectFactory, so theoritically, as stated in the ObjectFactory javadoc :

```
/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the org.contract.schemas.yyyy.xx.some_contracts package. 
 * (...) 
 */
```

I checked :

- Maven version : 3.0.4 on laptop / 3.0.5 on Jenkins
- CXF codegen plugin : as the version is specified in the pom, it's the same on both environment(2.7.5)
- Generated ObjectFactory : 7754 lines on laptop / 2754 lines on Jenkins.

Why are they 5000 missing lines?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Finally, I found a workaround by eliminating the need of using ObjectFactory using a bindings.xml file (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413281/how-do-i-prevent-jaxbelementstring-from-being-generated-in-a-cxf-web-service-c) )